# -webkit-transform: producing jagged lines in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Using the following code, I am placing objects at an angle on either side of a web page. One angles the div to the left a bit, and the other to the right.

To the left:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg) ;
```

To the right:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-45deg);
```

**Screenshots of the issue:**

[100% Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdF6o.png)

As you can see, in Chrome the edges have become very jagged at the normal zoom level.

[300% Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RGAa.png)

At 300%, the lines become much clearer....why is this?

[500% Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XSXo.png)

At 500%, while I cannot scroll very far into the image, I am able to tell a much bigger difference than the 100% zoom and I am unsure as to why. You would think the opposite would be true, given that when zooming in I am supposedly 'blowing it up'...I may be assuming too much here. *So I ask the community,* **why are my lines becoming jagged, after** `-webkit-transform: translateX(-350px) translateZ(-200px) rotateY(45deg) ;`

I have tried some things, including adding this:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

or this:

```
 /* Due to a bug in the anti-liasing*/
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
 -webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);
```

with no success...

I can provide a link, if necessary to the code that I am working with, however I feel that the line of code I have provided might be the culprit itself.

Thank you,

James

**Edit:** I felt that an image of the div without the webkit-transform applied to it was necessary.

[Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoqqT.png)

Comment: This is just a stretch (pun, definitely intended) I think I was squeezing my image with the transform. The container div was set to `420px` and I was shrinking it down with the `translateZ(-200px)` 

Adjusting the translateZ to -100px made it better, albeit larger. I think I have to adjust my div sizes accordingly. 

I'll mark this as the answer if it ends up being, but feel free to contribute.

Comment: BINGO! I created my image to be 50% smaller than the 420px X 60px div it was going to fill (210px x 30px) and applied `background-size: 100%` to blow the image out, and it now looks good in 100% zoom. Just have to adjust some hues, and we're golden. I'll leave this here for any future **-webkit-transform jagged images** Googlers to enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I created my image to be 50% smaller than the 420px X 60px div it was going to fill (210px x 30px) and applied background-size: 100% to blow the image out, and it now looks good in 100% zoom. Just have to adjust some hues, and we're golden. I'll leave this here for any future -webkit-transform jagged images Googlers to enjoy.